# Autocomplete POSTing comma separated values or an array

Tags: jquery, mysql, json, autocomplete

So now that I got the autosuggest working... I want to get my form to actual POST the input values.  So currently if I just run search.php, I get the following:

{"label":"Henry Gale","value":"henrygale@gmail.com"},{"label":"Amy Gerges","value":"amy@yahoo.com"}, and the list goes on.

So since the search is working properly.  Now, I want to POST only the values that I place in the form's input field. I currently have:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#autocomp" ).autoSuggest("search.php", {
        minChars: 2, 
        selectedItemProp: "label", 
        searchObjProps: "label", 
                    selectedValuesProp: "value",
        selectionLimit: 8, 
        formatList: function(data, elem){
            var my_image = data.image ;
            var my_label = data.label;
            var new_elem = elem.html(my_image + my_label);
            return new_elem;}
    });
}); </script> <input name="contacts[]" type="text" id="autocomp" maxlength="35" />
```

So if I do an echo of the $_POST['contacts'] I get the word: Array

I am doing something wrong, just not sure what... Since my input gets a list of comma separated emails (value), how can I post these to be in an array, so I can do things with the emails (run them through format checks, insert them into a mysql db, etc).

Comment: The part where you are actually doing your POST-ing isn't listed in the example so its hard to know for sure. But I'm guessing you are POST-ing your object $_POST['contacts'] rather than serializing it first (ie, set $_POST['contacts'] equal to JSON.stringify(contacts)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why is your `<input>` `name` attribute equal to `"contacts[]"`? If your intention is to create a PHP array out of the entered data items, you'll need to do so on the server-side - simple JavaScript and HTML can't handle the creation of a PHP array for you.

I'm not 100% sure how `jQuery` Autosuggest works, but from your code it looks like it allows the user to select up to 8 items from the autocomplete list (I may be wrong). In any case, since you say you'll be getting a list of comma-separated emails as input, you'll have to separate them on the server and validate each email separately. You can separate them using the PHP [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function. After validation you could add the elements of the resultant array to the DB.

I would change the `name` parameter of `<input>` to be something like `"email_list_string"`.